# Validate Coupon Codes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xcode, validation, coupon

I am trying to get the code below to work.  If i enter in the correct coupon code it still give me the "Sorry, The Coupon Code you entered is invalid. Please check and try again!" message.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script language = "javascript"> 
function validate(coupon) { 
codes = new Object();
codes.GOLD20 = 20;
codes.GOLD = 30;
codes.GOLD40 = 40;
codes.GOLD50 = 50;

if (codes[coupon]) 
 { 
 window.alert("Coupon Code Accepted! Click the Order button!"); 
 } 
else 
 { 
 window.alert("Sorry, The Coupon Code you entered is invalid. Please check and try again!"); 
 } 
} 
</script>
```

Here is the html:

```
<input type="text" name="text1"> 
<input type="button" value="Validate Coupon" name="Submit" 
    onclick="validate()">`
```

If you see any errors in my code please let me know or if you you know why i am not getting the alert for the Coupon code accepted please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your no value is passed to validate. When you click, `validate()` gets called, with no parameter, so `coupon` is undefined.

The HTML should be:

```
<input type="text" name="text1"> 
   <input type="button" value="Validate Coupon" name="Submit" 
   onclick="validate(document.getElementsByName('text1')[0].value)">
```

Live [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ewm43yc1/)

Comment: THANK YOU!  That worked perfectly.  

I just tested code out.  and it works well.  Now can i ask you if i wanted to run the javascript with out the button is there a way?  Like run the script when focus is off text1?